# Ubuntu 16.10 Video Closed Captioning

Tags: video-player

Every time I play a video that has closed captioning embedded, I see the closed captioning on the screen.
How do I turn-off closed captioning for videos in 16.10?

Comment: Use the subtitles settings of the player where you can enable/ disable or toggle subtitles.

Answer (score 0):

There's no universal answer, it depends on the video player you're using.

In default **Ubuntu Videos** you can turn of the CC by

> View -> Subtitles -> None

In other video players it's different, for example in **VLC** it's

> Subtitle -> Sub Track -> Disable